# Python Selenium how to move mouse on element. which shows drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium

link http://www.babylegs.com

My code:

```
class TestClassMy(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()


    def test1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('http://www.babylegs.com')
        driver.maximize_window()
        element_to_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/ol/li[5]/a") #d.send_keys(Keys.NULL)

        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        element_to_select.click_and_hold(element_to_select).perform()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your browser is Firefox, the Python code would look like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_id('your-id') # or your another selector here
action.move_to_element(element)
action.perform()
```

If you have already moved your cursor to an element and want to re-position it relatively, you can use:

```
action.move_by_offset(10, 20)    # 10px to the right, 20px to bottom
action.perform()
```

or even shorter:

```
action.move_by_offset(10, 20).perform()
```

More documentation is here:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the ActionChains like:

```
actions.move_to_element(element_to_select).perform()
```

Then you can do what you need. This is how you'll work with dropdown menus, by `finding` the elements, then performing a chain to essentially moves the mouse into the right places.

Then, once the menu (and submenus) have been exposed, you can click on them (as you see, you cannot click on things not visible.

In your case, to select something from the "Socks" menu:

```
e1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/ol/li[5]/a')
e2 = e1.find_element_by_xpath('../ul/li[1]/a')
actions.move_to_element(e1).move_to_element(e2).perform()
e2.click()
```

Comment: Bro, respect to you!
My final code looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/481d67e4acaf6dad642d462cc4ff0fd3

FOR SOME REASON IT DOESN'T WORK ON FIREFOX ((((
When I change browser to chrome it statred! Could you help me with Firefox?

Comment: If you're getting the error message, `moveto did not match a known command`, it appears Firefox support for actions has been limited. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285 for example. That bug report indicates a fix 15 days ago, so perhaps if you upgrade to newest Selenium (3.3+) and newest geckodriver (0.15+) it will be working.